How can I programmatically toggle checkboxes in Salesforce User Interface settings?
I'm seeking guidance on adjusting settings in Salesforce under Setup > User Interface. Specifically, I need to programmatically toggle checkboxes based on user requirements. Could anyone advise me on the best approach to achieve this using Salesforce APIs or another recommended method?
Thank you for your help!

Settings are accessible via Metadata API. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_userinterfacesettings.htm

To manipulate them from Apex you'd need to make a callout to Metadata API. I don't see the object available in Tooling API but might be worth digging around before really discarding the idea.
If you indeed need metadata - there's a wrapper class to make the callouts bit simpler, check https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi out.
